# How to loop over arraylist and sorting based on starting character

Tags: java

This was my assignment:

*Write and test a method that takes a List words, which contains Strings of alphabetic characters, throws them into 26 "buckets", according to the first letter, and returns the ArrayList of buckets. Each bucket should be represented by an ArrayList. The first bucket should contain all the Strings from words that start with an 'a', in the same order as they appear in words; the second bucket should contain all the Strings that start with a 'b'; and so on. Your method should traverse the list words only once and leave it unchanged.*

So far my code looks like this:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bucketSort(ArrayList<String> arr) {
        // Generate 26 bucket list
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bucket = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(26);
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            bucket.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        }
        // Sort by char
        for (String v : arr) {
            for (int c=97; c <=122; c++) {
                if (v.startsWith(String.valueOf((char) c))) {
                    bucket.get(97-c).add(v.toUpperCase());
                }
            }
        }
        return bucket;
    }
```

The only problem is that i'm getting indexoutofbounds error and I'm not sure why. The `97` and `122` refers to chars 'a' - 'z'. Think its correct because `(int) 'a'` gives me 97 and 122 for 'z'. I'm confused on why I'm getting index out of bounds.

Comment: "The 97 and 122 refers to chars 'a' - 'z'" you could have used `'a'` and `'z'` directly.

Comment: You are getting the error because of this line ```bucket.get(97-c).add(v.toUpperCase());```

Comment: What do you think `97-c` is? Do you think it is non-negative or negative?

Comment: @AndyTurner well I thought if the str starts with 97 then 97-97 would land it at index 0. But I'm not really sure.

Comment: @EDWINCHEN sure, 97-97 is 0. But what's 97-98?

Comment: because of ```97-c ``` your calculation becomes negative for larger number , which is not there in the list. Hence you should use ```c-97``` . see my answer for detailed explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The IndexOutOfBounds is because you have your subtraction backwards by using `97-c` instead of `c-97`.

You could also iterate by chars to simplify your code:

```
public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bucketSort(ArrayList<String> arr) {
    // Generate 26 bucket list
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bucket = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(26);
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        bucket.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    // Sort by char
    for (String v : arr) {
        for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
            if (v.startsWith(c) || v.startsWith(Character.toUpperCase(c)) {
                bucket.get(c - 'a').add(v.toUpperCase());
            }
        }
    }
    return bucket;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because of this line `bucket.get(97-c).add(v.toUpperCase());` . In this line , you are trying to access the  ArrayList using `97-c` . , but if the char is `'b'` , the then value of c becomes 98 and your `97-c` resolves to `97-98` which is throwing IndexOutOfBounds exception.

You will have to modify that line as

`bucket.get(c-97).add(v.toUpperCase());`  .

In this way , if the starting letter is "a", your `c-97` gets resolved as `97-97` which equals `0` and hence you will get `bucket.get(0)`  . and if your starting letter is "f" would resolve to `102-97` and you will get `bucket.get(5)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try change places c and 97 in subtraction.

If c=97 then 97-97=0,

If c=122 then 122-97=25.

And also you do not process words wich begins with upper letter. If you wan to have only 26 case insensitive buckets so convert before search to lower case:

```
  public static ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bucketSort(ArrayList<String> arr) {
    // Generate 26 bucket list
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> bucket = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>(26);
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        bucket.add(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    // Sort by char
    for (String v : arr) {
        for (int c=97; c <=122; c++) {
            if (v.toLowerCase().startsWith(String.valueOf((char) c))) {
                bucket.get(c-97).add(v.toUpperCase());
            }
        }
    }
    return bucket;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        for (String v : arr) {
            for (int c=97; c <=122; c++) {
                if (v.startsWith(String.valueOf((char) c))) {
                    bucket.get(97-c).add(v.toUpperCase());
                }
            }
        }
```

There is no point in looping over all characters here: a string starts with one character, a fixed character; so just check that.

```
        for (String v : arr) {
            if (v.isEmpty()) continue;

            char c = v.charAt(0);
            if (c < 'a' || c > 'z') continue;

            int bucketIndex = c - 'a';
            bucket.get(bucketIndex).add(v.toUpperCase());
        }
```

Note that `bucketIndex` is `c - 'a'` (or `c - 97`), not `97 - c`, since the bucket for `'z'` needs to be 25 (`'z' - 'a'`), not -25.